# Asp.Net MVC WebGrid paging...is there an alternative to putting data in session?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I finally got my MVC WebGrid paging to work and my drop downlist box criteira to maintain state!!  I did this by putting the result data and criteria data in session for when the 'next page' is click on the grid and everything could be re-populated.  Is there another, more appropriate way to do this without loading up a bunch of session varables?

HERE IS MY CONTROLER CODE:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Results(TestCriteriaConsolidated form) 
    { 
        List<TestCriteriaResults> gridResults = new List<TestCriteriaResults>();
        gridResults.Add(new TestCriteriaResults { Value1 = "one", Value2 = "one", Value3 = "three", Value4 = "Four" });
        gridResults.Add(new TestCriteriaResults { Value1 = "one", Value2 = "two", Value3 = "three", Value4 = "four" });
        gridResults.Add(new TestCriteriaResults { Value1 = "one", Value2 = "two", Value3 = "three", Value4 = "four" });
        gridResults.Add(new TestCriteriaResults { Value1 = "one", Value2 = "two", Value3 = "three", Value4 = "four" });
        gridResults.Add(new TestCriteriaResults { Value1 = "one", Value2 = "two", Value3 = "three", Value4 = "four" });

        Session["GridResults"] = gridResults;
        Session["SelectedYear"] = form.testCriteria.Year;
        form.testCriteriaResults = gridResults;             

        return View(form); 
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Results()
    {
        List<TestCriteriaResults> gridResults = ((List<TestCriteriaResults>) Session["GridResults"]);
        TestCriteria criteria = new TestCriteria() { Year = Session["SelectedYear"].ToString() };
        TestCriteriaConsolidated combined = new TestCriteriaConsolidated { testCriteriaResults = gridResults, testCriteria = criteria };

        return View(combined);
    }
```

HERE IS CODE FROM MY PARIAL VIEW:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Results", "Home"))
{
 <div style="float:left">
                <div style="font-weight:bold">                
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.testCriteria.Year)
                </div>
                <div style="width:110px; ">   
                     @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.testCriteria.Year, new SelectList(new[] 
                     { 

                        new SelectListItem{ Text="All Years", Value=" " },
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="2010", Value="2010" },
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="2009", Value="2009" },
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="2008", Value="2008" },
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="2007", Value="2007" },
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="2006", Value="2006" }

                     }, "Value", "Text", "1"), new { @style = "width: 100px; margin-top: 5px" })          
                </div>
    </div>

    <div style="float:left">
        <div>                
            &nbsp;
        </div>
        <div style="width:100px; ">                                
                <input type="submit"  value="Results" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

}

HERE IS MY VIEW CODE TO DISPLAY THE GRID WITH RESULTS:

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.TestCriteriaConsolidated


       @{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}


@if (Model == null || Model.testCriteriaResults == null)
{

}
else
{


var grid = new WebGrid(Model.testCriteriaResults,canPage: true, rowsPerPage: 2);
@grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.Numeric);     


    <div id="grid">
        @grid.GetHtml()

    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is an alternative. Make sure you get the selected year in a query string parameter and then you don't need a session variable to hold the data. The pager will then parese the query string parameter and appended it automatically to the pager links.

One way to do this is to

```
public ActionResult Search(string year)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Results", new { searchString = year });
}
```

And make sure your results method accepts a string parameter (or whatever datatype you want).